# Photostream screensaver on apple tv3 and ios 10.x?

Tags: icloud, appletv, photo-stream, ios

I have always had whatever photos I take with my iphone, automagically in my photostream, and those then making up the screensaver of my apple tv 3. I guess with whatever is different with apple photos/photostream now, this connection doesn't work any longer.

Any suggestions?

The iphone and apple tv are signed in to the same icloud account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at some point, `Settings`->`iCloud`->`iCloud Photos Settings` got a new option: `iCloud Photo Sharing`. I'm pretty sure enabling this is what allowed me to select my photos as before.